# Bitbucket and Jenkins remote build trigger

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, webhooks

**What I am trying to achieve**

Trigger a build from Bitbucket when a pull request is created using the remote trigger option in Jenkins. So I created a job in Jenkins and configured to trigger a build with the remote API.

[image]

In Bitbucket I created a webhook to trigger the build with the following URL structure:

```
http://jenkins_server_ip:port/job/job-name/build?token=<t1>
```

I get the following error:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
        <p>Problem accessing /job/android-sample/build. Reason:

            <pre>    No valid crumb was included in the request</pre>
        </p>
        <hr>
        <a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a>
        <hr/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I digged into the internet and some says that we need to use the *crumbIssuer* API in Jenkins which is done with `wget`. How can I use this in Bitbucket?

Answer (score 0):

You can close the CSRF security check in: system configure → *Configure Global Security* → *CSRF Protection*, and uncheck the checkbox.

Comment: Which leaves you open to...?

Answer (score -1):

You have to get the crumb key from Jenkins first and insert it into your build request's HTTP header. The crumb is for protecting from CSRF attacks.

The following Bash commands uses curl to send the build request, and it works well:

```
CRUMB=`curl -u $USER:$PASS 'http://$SERVER:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'`
curl -H $CRUMB -u $USER:PASS 'http://$SERVER:8080/job/$PROJECT/build?token=$UR_TOKEN'
```